# Partial View not working in IE7, but works fine in FF, Chrome (MVC 3, JQuery Tab Container)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I was thinking maybe this has something to do with my jquery, but I'm not sure. When I fill data into one tab and navigate to the next, then back to the first the data is there in FF and Chrome, but not in IE. Could you take a look at the jquery which loads the tab container. Maybe I have something wrong with it? Thanks

Figured it out - all the code posting wasn't necessary.

While on the second tab, I cleared IE's cache and went back to the first and it data appeared. Thanks IE.

Comment: Where does the variable `createToken` get its value?  Also, it might be worth posting the html you are running the jQuery with.

Comment: I've included the html. createToken is set from a guid in the controller. Thanks

Comment: Provide the HTML sample output from one of the tabs: `OfficeNameTab?CreateToken=194a19b6-9f50-4e39-b24e-726ba1645bda`

Comment: I have provided the html sample from the OfficeNameTab. Thanks

Comment: Chrome and FF has a feature where they pre-populate the textboxes that you filled out before while IE does not.  Something must be resetting the page state when you click back to the first tab.  I also failed to understand the role of the partial as your title suggests.

Comment: Roman - When switching tabs, the post of the current tab saves it's contents, and the get of the tab I'm going to gets the contents of the tab going to. The load method triggered by the GET should populate the controls.

Comment: Something else I wanted to point out. In the GET method of my controllers I have a ModelState.Clear() call so that the validation messages do not display when the tab is loaded. Could that cause this error? I tried removing each but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Figured it out. While on the second tab, I cleared IE's cache and went back to the first and it data appeared. Thanks IE.